# Как удалить arraylist,из Sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-shared-preferences

Я храню ArrayList со строковыми значениями в Sharedpreferences,мне нужно удалить только ArrayList,а остальные значения хранящиеся в Sharedpreferences(настройки пользователя и.т.д) оставить без изменений,но при попытке удаления ArrayList,удаляются и остальные значения хранящиеся в Sharedpreferences.

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPrefs.getString("stars", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BoughtProduct>>() {
    }.getType();
    final ArrayList<BoughtProduct> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

 deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (arrayList!=null)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                arrayList.clear();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SharedPreference.setTotalPrice(getApplication(),"");
                SharedPreference.setProductPosition(getApplication(),"");
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Корзина очищена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(MyBasket.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Нет товаров в корзине!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удаляйте по ключу.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.remove(String key);
```

Вообще, можно разные файлы использовать для сохранения данных разных типов.